# wpa_supplicant and network management tools

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have a well configured `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with all my ESSIDs and passwords. I do not have a graphical interface like KDE or Gnome.
To switch between available networks, I need to do four commands.

I'm running Debian and would like to have a utility similar to Arch's Linux [netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl) to manage my connections. What are the options available to Debian?

Comment: I've not used it but there is `wicd-cli` if that corresponds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two option are `wicd-cli` (noted in the comment by meuh) and `networkmanager`.  Which to use is matter of personal preference.  I use `networkmanager` just because it has a better manual (but that, again, is matter of preference).

Just like `wpa_supplicant` stores files in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` **one per interface**, `networkmanager` stores files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` **one per SSID**.  The parameter names for `networkmanager` are not very different from `wpa_supplicant`, for example a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` may look as follows:

```
[connection]
id=BluePenguin
uuid=799ce6af-b66c-4669-9319-8d9a029cb6ee
type=wifi

[wifi]
ssid=BluePenguin

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=******
```

(This looks similar to `network={}` in `wpa_supplicant`)

My experience with `networkmanager` is on Arch, not Debian, therefore I cannot tell with 100% accuracy on the Debian dependency chain.  But, `networkmanager` does not require Xorg (or GTK, or KDE).

Moreover, the command line tool to `networkmanager`: `nmcli`, is very similar in design to `iproute2`.  In essence, as you would do:

```
ip addr help
```

to get help for the `addr` command, you do:

```
nmcli device wifi help
```

to get help on all `wifi` commands for `devices`.  Since I use `ip` a lot, I find `nmcli` very intuitive, but then again, that is matter of personal preference.

`networkmanager` has a built-in DHCP client, but can be configured to use an external one.

---

As for reducing the number of commands, `nmcli` will perform the work of disconnecting from one SSID (closing DHCP too) and connect to a new SSID (and start DHCP) with on command (assuming the password is already saved):

```
nmcli device wifi connect <new SSID>
```

Or for the lazy typer:

```
nmcli d w c <new SSID>
```

References:

- [Debian wiki on Network Manager](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager)
- [Arch wiki on Network Manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager)

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct, although `networkmanager` isn't the exact tool I was hoping to find. But it gets closer. Thanks!

Comment: @WillianPaixao - Network managers in linux had a hard time recently when everyone started moving to systemd (but thank god, everyone if there now).  Now that the init system stabilized, i believe, there will be new attempts at network management (notably because things like `ifup` finally died out).  I find `nmcli` pretty intuitive and decent enough to even debug my wifi problems.  `wicd-cli`/`wicd-curses` (as meuh commented) may be another option but i never used it so I am not entitled to an opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You can manage network from command line through:

1)[`wpa_cli`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_cli)

I assumes that `wpa_supplicant` is already running .

type:

```
nmcli
```

It will show a prompt similar to this:

```
wpa_cli v2.3
Copyright (c) 2004-2014, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


 Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode
```

You can scan for the networks using :

```
scan
```

and

```
scan_results
```

You will get some information : bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid

To connect you need to  create a network :

```
add_network
```

This will output a number, which is the network ID, e,g: `0`

The command `add_network` will create an empty network, to configure it you need to set the `SSID` and `PSK` for the network:

```
set_network 0 ssid "your_Network_here"
set_network 0 psk "your_secret_passphrase_here"
```

Enable and save the network and settings:

```
enable network 0
save_config
```

Once connected , run the `dhclient` command to get an IP.

Use `q` or `quit` to exit the Interactive mode.

2) Using [`wpa_supplicant`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant)

Create a configuration file `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` throught the command `wpa_passphrase`:

```
wpa_passphrase Your_ssid Your_passphrase > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

to connect run:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: `wpa_cli`is exaclty what I'm currently using, @gad3r. It takes too much "trouble" too switch between networks. Not to mention that the whole `wpa_supplicant`has half dozen commands and too many options. But thanks for your answer.